# No public static parameters method on class. JUnit tests

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Пишу тесты на приложение, решил определить их всех в один набор аннотацией @RunWith(Suite.class), но после объединение не проходит параметризированный тест и выводит ошибку No public static parameters method on class.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

**AllTests:**

```
@Suite.SuiteClasses( { ItemDaoTest.class, MySqlDaoFactoryTest.class} )
@RunWith(Suite.class)
public class AllTests {

}
```

**ItemDaoTest:**

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public abstract class ItemDaoTest{

protected abstract ItemDao<Entity> dao();

protected Class<? extends Entity> daoClass;

protected Entity dto;

public ItemDaoTest(Class<? extends Entity> clazz, Entity dto) {
    this.daoClass = clazz;
    this.dto = dto;
}

@Test
public void testGetById() throws Exception {
    dto = dao().getById(1);
    Assert.assertNotNull(dto);
}


@Test
public void testGetAll() throws Exception{
    List<? extends Entity> list = dao().getAll();
    Assert.assertNotNull(list);
    Assert.assertTrue(list.size()>0);
}

@Test
public void testDelete() throws Exception{
    List<? extends Entity> list = dao().getAll();
    Assert.assertNotNull(list);

    int oldSize = list.size();
    Assert.assertTrue(oldSize>0);

    dao().delete(list.get(0));

    list = dao().getAll();
    Assert.assertNotNull(list);

    int newSize = list.size();
    Assert.assertEquals(1, oldSize-newSize);
}

}
```

**MySqlDaoFactoryTest:**

```
public class MySqlDaoFactoryTest extends ItemDaoTest{

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MySqlDaoFactoryTest.class);

public MySqlDaoFactoryTest(Class<? extends Entity> clazz, Entity dto) {
    super(clazz, dto);
}

private Connection connection;

private ItemDao<? extends Entity> dao;


@BeforeClass
public static void init() throws DBException{

     try {
            // Create initial context
            System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
            System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
                "org.apache.naming");
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

            ic.createSubcontext("java:");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

            // Construct DataSource
            MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource(); 
            ds.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital"); 
            ds.setUser("root"); 
            ds.setPassword("    "); 

            ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/hospital", ds); 

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            LOG.trace(ex);
        }
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getParameters() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {Patient.class, new Patient()}
            {User.class, new User()},
            {Reception.class, new Reception()},
            {Task.class, new Task()},
            {Procedure.class, new Procedure()}

    });
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws DBException, SQLException {
    DaoFactory factory = new MySqlDaoFactory();
    connection = factory.getConnection();
    LOG.trace("Obtain connection: "+connection);
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    dao = factory.getDao(connection, daoClass);
    LOG.trace("Obtain dao: "+dao);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws SQLException {
    connection.rollback();
    connection.close();
}

@Override
public ItemDao<Entity> dao() {
    return (ItemDao<Entity>) dao;
}
}
```

**Стек-трейс:**

```
java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class ua.nure.martseniuk.SummaryTask4.db.dao.ItemDaoTest
at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.getParametersMethod(Parameterized.java:299)
at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:246)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:102)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:107)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**P.S.:** Пишу тесты на дао, слышал, что это плохая затея, но так надо.

Comment: трейс кидайте, пожалуйста

Comment: вопрос дополнен

Comment: пробуй внутри `getParameters() `  инициализировать  типа `Collection<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<>();`  наполнять ее, а потом возвращать  `params`

Answer (score 2):

JUnit ясно говорит, в чем проблема: в классе `ItemDaoTest` отсутствует публичный статический метод, предоставляющий параметры (т.е. помеченный аннотацией `@Parameters`). Метод для получения параметров ищется в том же классе, который помечен аннотацией `@Parametrized`.

Вам нужно переместить метод `getParameters()` в `ItemDaoTest`. Либо вообще объединить эти два класса -- если у вас единственная реализация DAO (т.е. рядом нет еще чего-нибудь вроде `OracleDaoFactoryTest`), то смысла в разделении немного.